# Display only one branch on Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, build

I'm starting to setup Jenkins in my company and I have several projects with several git branches each. There is job for each project which builds every git branch that receive a push or a pull request using the GitHub plugin.

As a result, the view of a project shows only the last branch built. My question is: Is there any way to have a view showing only development builds?

The reason I don't want to have a separate job for each branch is that if by any chance the dev job runs at the same time as the other branches job, they'll both use the db and will fail.for

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Javier

Comment: It is not clear from your question whether you want the job to be triggered only for the development branch or to run it for all branches but to show only the run of the development branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a freestyle job, where you can specify the branch specifically, and not a multibranch pipeline job, you could have one branch polling and set the others branch build jobs as downstream jobs.

You could also consider using the [Build Blocker](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin) plugin.

Either of those approaches would work but would be a little awkward.

Any testing against the database needs to be idempotent, if it isn't you should rethink your process.